# Xamarin.Mac - Unit Testing PdfKit

Tags: c#, nunit, xunit, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

How can I run unit tests (`XUnit`, `NUnit`, `VSTest`) for a `Xamarin.Mac Project` in Visual Studio Mac?

I need to test code that uses `Foundation.PdfKit`.

I tried `NUnit3` test, but cannot create `NSUrl` for local file.

```
new NSUrl("/home/xyz/Downloads/xyz.pdf", false);
```

throws an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: NSUrl is an IoS class and not part of any of the three test frameworks listed. IOW you  need to reference an assembly that defines it, possibly xamarin.ios.dll.

Comment: In my case i referenced xamarin.mac.dll. I get a ArgumentNullException instantiating the NSUrl. I think this came from converting System.String to NSString.

Comment: This is not straight forward. Xamarin.Mac.dll must be referenced, the libxammac.dylib must be found, you also need to ensure the NSApplication.Init method is called once. The recommendation is to use GuiUnit as described in this stack overflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217848/xamarin-mac-unit-test-project